# How to sort array of objects using values from a second array

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects and I need to sort them by the values of an attribute. The order to sort is given in the second array.

```
a = [ object1, object2, object3, object4]

object1.job = 'ER'
object2.job = 'AD'
object3.job = 'WE'
object4.job = 'ER'

b = ['ER', 'ER', 'WE', 'AD']
```

I need to sort my array `a` so that it returns `[object1/object4, object3, object2]`. How can I use my array `b` as a key for the sorting?

Comment: Your ordering given by `b` is contradictory. It means that `ER` precedes (and follows) itself.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
sorted_a = a.sort_by { |obj| b.index obj.job }
```

Note that `b` doesn't need to have multiple copies of `ER`; it just needs to indicate that `ER` comes before `WE` and `AD`.

```
b = ['ER', 'WE', 'AD']
```

The `index` function returns the position of its argument in its invocant:

```
b.index 'ER'  #=> 0
b.index 'AD'  #=> 2
```

And the `sort_by` method runs the supplied block on each element of the array and uses the results as the keys to sort by.

Comment: Good point about `ER`. Actually, what OP gave is contradictory. It means that `ER` precedes (and follows) itself.